# C# debugging breakpoints not available for project source files, only decompiled DLLs

Tags: c#, debugging, dependencies, rider

I have a project I need to debug, let's call it `BigProject\Infrastructure\src\ServiceClient.csproj`, for which I would like to set breakpoints in the source code, step into it and so on.

It is included as a project reference by a project `BigProject\RESTService\src\RESTServiceClient.csproj` which is then included as a project reference by `BigProject\GatewayEndpoint\src\GatewayEndpoint.csproj`, which is what I am running in debug mode.

Unfortunately when I try to set a breakpoint (using Jetbrains Rider) in a source file in the `ServiceClient.csproj` project directory, I get the `not found among the loaded symbol documents` error.

When I try to step through into the code of a `ServiceClient.csproj` class, it redirects me to a decompiled DLL which is irritating to step through and debug.

Lastly if I try to include `ServiceClient.csproj` as a project reference in `BigProject\GatewayEndpoint\src\GatewayEndpoint.csproj` I get the `An assembly with  the same simple name has already been imported` error.

How do I make it so I can seamlessly set breakpoints in the source code and step into it?

Comment: Are you sure you are running the same thing that you are building? This is something that should work by default, so it might be some odd configuration error. It might help to create a new project, test that that works, and see if your projects are configured differently.